# R package : Problem to manage API client secret in Vignette

Tags: r, package, cran

I have trouble with CRAN check when I upload my package. My goal is to hide the secret client API ID in the package source, but I need it to build the vignette and the CRAN try to re-build it.

This [article](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/vignettes/secrets.html) answer exactly my problem but don't solve it :

> Vignettes pose additional challenges when an API requires authentication, because you don’t want to bundle your own credentials with the package! However, you can take advantage of the fact that the vignette is built locally, and only checked by CRAN. In a setup chunk, do:
>
> `NOT_CRAN <- identical(tolower(Sys.getenv("NOT_CRAN")), "true")`
> `knitr::opts_chunk$set(purl = NOT_CRAN)`
> And then use `eval = NOT_CRAN` in any chunk that requires access to a secret.

---

Add `eval=NOT_CRAN` in the chunk I want to keep secret works for Rstudio check/build (0 errors/ 0 warning & 0 notes), but when I upload to CRAN the package is refused while building the vignette : the chunk with `eval=NOT_CRAN` is not executed by CRAN, but CRAN try to rebuild the vignette and need it.

The article says that

> you can take advantage of the fact that the vignette is built locally, and only checked by CRAN

but in my case **CRAN try to rebuild my vignette** :

log error :

> Error(s) in re-building vignettes:
>
> --- re-building ‘myvignette.Rmd’ using rmarkdown
>
> ...
>
> --- failed re-building ‘myvignette.Rmd’

Thanks for any help,

Jul